# Why does touchpad button work under KDE but not GNOME?

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04. The button worked when booted to Ubuntu Studio Live (KDE), but not on my HDD .

Comment: Ubuntu Studio was 18.10?   If that's the case, it could be kernel related, and switching to the HWE kernel would solve your issue (thus is a thought only; as I don't know Ubuntu Studio you tried, nor if's your issue - you could always try Ubuntu 18.10 (live) & if it works there too - HWE kernel would probably be the issue, as that forces Ubuntu 18.04 use the 18.10 kernel, 19.04, 19.10 then 20.04 in due course).   ie. later kernels have additional drivers for more modern hardware which HWE gets access to..

Comment: Ubuntu Studio uses the XFCE desktop environment by default, not KDE.